# How can I get the index of non-sibling elements in jquery?

Tags: javascript, jquery

HTML:

```
<ul>
    <li>Help</li>
    <li>me</li>
    <li>Stack</li>
    <li>Overflow!</li>
</ul>

<br>

<ul>
    <li>Can</li>
    <li>I</li>
    <li>connect</li>
    <li>these?</li>
</ul>
```

Javascript/JQuery:

```
$("li").live('click', function(){

alert($(this).index());

});
```

I put together a simple jsfilled page to help describe my problem: http://jsfiddle.net/T4tz4/

Currently clicking on an LI alerts the index relative to the current UL group. I'd like to know if it was possible to get a 'global index' so that clicking on "Can" returns the index value of 4.

Thank you,
John

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Just put the `'li'` selector inside `index()`

```
$('li').live('click', function() {
    alert( $(this).index('li') );
});
```

**Live demo:** http://jsfiddle.net/T4tz4/3/

---

http://api.jquery.com/index/

> If a selector string is passed as an
>   argument, .index() returns an integer
>   indicating the position of the
>   original element relative to the
>   elements matched by the selector.

Answer (score 4):

Here's a solution:
http://jsfiddle.net/T4tz4/1/

```
$("li").each(function(index) {$(this).data("index",index);});

$("li").live('click', function(){

    alert($(this).data("index"));

});
```

Comment: +1, nice... I missed what the asker wanted but this is obviously it

Comment: Why make us click a link, when your solution is only 4 lines of code? And what happens if/when jsfiddle is dead? Post the code here instead, or in addition...

Comment: @peirix, it's a link where people could test it live. So it doesn't matter how many lines of code there are. I do however agree that code also belongs here.